# Showing text file in notepad using electron

Tags: electron

I am working on a electron application, in which I have to show the licence file in notepad to the user. Is it possible to show the `*.txt` file to user using electron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="open_txt()">Show file</button>
```

JS:

```
var app = require('electron').remote; 
function open_txt(){
  app.shell.openExternal('yourfile.txt');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.